# Can I stop Sinatra from within a Sinatra application?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, exit

I'd like to know how to programmatically exit a Sinatra application from *within* the application itself.  (There's another SO thread about stopping it from outside the app.)

I want to use Sinatra as a means of receiving control and configuration commands while my application does something unrelated to the Sinatra stuff.  I'd like one of the control commands to be 'exit'.  Ruby's 'exit' method just seems to result in Sinatra recovering and resuming.  I found this in base.rb that I think confirms this:

```
at_exit { Application.run! if $!.nil? && Application.run? }
```

So far, the only way I've found is to call Ruby's `exit!` method, but that bypasses `exit` hooks and is not a very clean solution.

Is there no way to programmatically tell Sinatra to stop?

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember what I was needing this for 8 years ago when I posted the question. I suppose I wanted to terminate if some external condition was met. I think @bigtunacan's approach is (unfortunately, because I don't really like monkey patching) the best one. I could start a thread which did the checking and called `exit!` when necessary. (cont'd.)

Comment: ...That would bypass all exit hooks in addition to Sinatra's I guess, which I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following code:

```
# Exit 'correctly'
get '/exit' do
  # /exit causes:
  # 15:20:24 web.1  | Damn!
  # 15:20:24 web.1  | exited with code 1
  Process.kill('TERM', Process.pid)
end

# Just terminate
get '/fail' do
  Process.kill('KILL', Process.pid)
end
```

Take a look at `at_exit` in [config.ru](https://github.com/qatsi/alpine-sinatra/blob/master/app/sinatra/config.ru) it works for TERM signal:

```
at_exit do
  puts 'Damn!'
  exit false
end
```

Full example is [here](https://github.com/qatsi/alpine-sinatra/blob/master/app/sinatra/app.rb).

Cheers.

Comment: Would this behave identically to calling `exit!`?

Answer (score 1):

That sort of goes against the grain of Sinatra, but this is just Ruby so you can easily do this via open classes/monkey patching.

Just re-open the base.rb `at_exit` method and override the `Application.run!` behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just raise an exception? That will mean that `$!` is not nil, so the `at_exit` handler won't restart Sinatra.

An easy way is just to run `fail` or `raise`. You can also pass a message, such as `fail "Exiting due to x"`.

Comment: Thanks, this would work, but would result in error output in the terminal in which Sinatra was started, and that output would not be trivial to differentiate with output resulting from a real error.

Answer (score 1):

`Sinatra::Base::quit!` or its alias `::stop!` is what you are looking for:

```rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/quit' do
  self.class.quit!
end

get '/stop' do
  self.class.stop!
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As mentioned in the question, I needed this to be called from within the server, and not be available to clients.